# iMacros Help! How can I extract the stock amount and put it in the form?

Tags: imacros

```
<input class="events-input form-input qtyInput" stock="10" value="1" type="text">
```

Here found from the element, and you can see the stock is 10.

But I want to extract the 10 and paste it below.

So I use the !VAR1 to in stead of the 10, but I can't extract the 10 because I always extract the 1 of the value.

```
TAG POS=3 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=* CONTENT={{!VAR1}}
```

Thanks!